# NameNotFoundException when calling getPackageInfo on Android 11

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-11

After setting `targetSdkVersion` to `30` (Android 11) I'm getting `android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException` when doing `packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)` on packages that I know exists.

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.apps.maps
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:202)
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:174)
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As stated in https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility:

> Android 11 changes how apps can query and interact with other apps
>   that the user has installed on a device. Using the new 
>   element, apps can define the set of other apps that they can access.
>   This element helps encourage the principle of least privilege by
>   telling the system which other apps to make visible to your app, and
>   it helps app stores like Google Play assess the privacy and security
>   that your app provides for users.
>
> If your app targets Android 11, you might need to add the 
>   element in your app's manifest file. Within the  element, you
>   can specify apps by package name or by intent signature.

So you either have to stop what you are doing, or request to access information about certain packages, or - if you have reasons for it - use the permission [`QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/Manifest.permission#query_all_packages).

## Query and interact with specific packages

To query and interact with specific packages you would update your `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.store" />
        <package android:name="com.example.services" />
    </queries>
    ...
     <application ...>
    ...
</manifest>
```

## Query and interact with all apps

I have an app that needs to be able to ask for information for all apps. All you have to do is to add the following to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest ...>
     ...
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
     ...
     <application ...>
     ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: If you public the app in the Play store, make sure your app qualifies for QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/package-visibility#all-apps

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" /> this tag got helped. Thanks. Interesting <queries>bla bla</queries> code not worked. merge manifest error.

Comment: I am getting quite a lot `NameNotFoundException`s for users with Android version below 11, e.g. for Android 7.1.1 on OnePlus.
I am not able to reproduce this myself so I am wondering if that could be caused by brand-specific package visibility protection.

Comment: A small portion of my users get this error when app requests info about its own package.

Answer (score 9):

In **AndroidManifest.xml** needed to add this both for **Android 11** and it works for me

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />


    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me on Android 12, thanks Roy & Rohit

with combination of both

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.example.store" />
    <package android:name="com.example.services" />
    <package android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```